# Files appeared in egg-info/source.txt but not in builded package

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm new to a python, I tried to build a package and faced this problem:

`Package structure:

package

```
- package_name
-- alembic
--- ...
-- backups
--- ...
--alembic.ini
-- __init__.py 
-- some .py files
- tests
- manifest.in
- pyproject.toml
- setup.py`
```

I registred package in manifest:
`graft package_name`

setup.py looks like that

```
setup(

    packages=["package_name"],

    package_dir={

        "package_name": "./package_name",

    },

    include_package_data=True
)
```

I'm using setuptools==61.0

After building I got all the files in SOURCES.txt in egg-info but after uploading package to nexus and installing I got only:

```
- package_name
- __init__.py
- some *.py files
```

in dist-info there is no files that was included in SOURCES.txt
I need to get package with alembic and backups in it. What else can I do to make this work?